# Get some fields in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I want to query subdocument which is "fields" object but the record return no results.

My code:

```
gares.find({"fields": ["id","fields.name"]};
```

"gares" Model

```
{"recordid": "1",
"fields": {
    "name":"verneuil",
    "country":"FR"
 },
"id": "585ab055578ee31431df8bf4"}
```

Response:

```
[{ "id": "585ab055578ee31431df8bf4"},]
```

I expect an output as:

```
[{ "id": "585ab055578ee31431df8bf4"}, "fields":{"name":"verneuil"}]
```

Someone help me please!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I expect an output as:  `[{ "id": "585ab055578ee31431df8bf4"}, "fields":{"name":"verneuil"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax,
Correct syntax as per [doc](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Fields-filter.html) is :

```
gares.find({"fields": {"id" : true,"fields.name" : true}};
```